# Is there a website for generating xíngshū (semi-cursive script) from jiǎnhuàzì (simplified characters)?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, calligraphy

Google Translate can be a useful tool for converting Simplified Chinese hanzi into Traditional Chinese — but I'm looking for a tool that will enable me to paste in a set of Simplified characters, and generate a calligraphic equivalent in semi-cursive script.

Is there a web service that does this, or would it be better to download a xíngshū font?

Comment: https://www.freechinesefont.com/ 
http://www.fonts.net.cn/fonts-zh-1.html

Comment: many more artistic fonts at 艺术字体控制台https://www.qt86.com/

Comment: Thank you! Those fonts are beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [第一字体网](http://www.diyiziti.com/)

Choose any 行书 fonts.

You can download the font too.

[image]

Comment: That site looks like exactly what I want, but doesn't seem to load for me. The connection just times out.